# Unable to remove all custom objects from array in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have array of custom objects. I am removing objects from that array but I am not able to remove the objects from that array here is my code.

```
if([arr_userFav count]>0)
        {
            int i;
            for (i=0; i<[arr_userFav count]; i++)
            {
                Post *objectCopy = [arr_userFav copy]; //create a copy of our object
                [arr_temp_Fav addObject: objectCopy];
            }
            NSLog(@"size of arr_temp_Fav %lu",(unsigned long)[arr_temp_Fav count]);

            [arr_userFav removeAllObjects];
        }
```

after removing objects form `arr_userFav` I have size of array as zero but when I put a breakpoint after it & see the objects in it then I don't get a empty array. Please tell how to do it?

**Below is the screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Please print arr_userFav on console. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not looking in `arr_temp_Fav` instead ? There is no reason to have objects in `arr_userFav` after calling `removeAllObjects`

Comment: post a screenshot of where u put the break point and where u see the objects in the console

Comment: please check my updated question.I have posted a screenshot.

Comment: It still doesn't prove you are looking at the right array at the right time.

Comment: In the `for` you are creating a copy of the array itself, not the object inside it. You should subscript the array with the index `i`. As a side note, in Objective-C the convention is to use camelCase, not snake_case nor a mixture of the two.

Comment: Yeah and if `copyWithZone` hasn't been implemented correctly that will cause mayhem to the objects, but that's a different question...

Comment: It's kind of unusual that you want to copy objects (other than container objects like arrays, dictionaries, sets).

Answer (score 1):

Please look very carefully at what your code is doing.

The object that you add to arr_temp_fav is a copy of arr_user_fav, that is a copy of the complete array. So if your array originally had ten elements, you now have an array with ten arrays as elements, each with ten elements itself. If you had 10,000 elements it's a lot worse.

```
Post *objectCopy = [arr_userFav copy]; //create a copy of our object
```

Here we have a case of a comment that would be completely pointless if it was correct - it is however incorrect and may be hiding from you what you are doing wrong.